# Cant understand why i am getting a keyerror in my django python app

Tags: python, django, dictionary, keyerror

I know that a key error is raised when a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary. But my key is there. It's telling me that the 'embed' key is the problem

heres my code

```
    def scrape_and_store_vlad():
        url_two = 'http://www.example.net'
        html = requests.get(url_two, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-1'})

        def make_soup(url):
            the_comments_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(the_comments_page.text, 'html5lib')
            comment = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'article-body'})
            para = comment.find_all('p')
            kids = [child.text for child in para]
            blu = str(kids).strip('[]')
            return blu
        name = 'vlad'
        entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                    'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                    'comments': make_soup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).replace("\\", ""),
                    'name': name,
                    'url': url_two + div.a.get('href')
                    } for div in titles][:6]

        # scraping from vlad part two
        titles_two = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'entry-pos-2'})

        entries_two = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                        'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                        'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                        'comments': make_soup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).replace("\\", ""),
                        'name': name,
                        'url': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                        'embed': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                         } for div in titles_two][:6]

        merged_vlad_entries = entries + entries_two

        return merged_vlad_entries


    def panties():
        from lxml import html
        pan_url = 'http://www.example.net'
        shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})
        name = 'pan videos'

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row]

            tubby = str(entries[4])
            urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
            return urls

        def embed(url):
            new_embed = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
            return new_embed

        entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[1],
                    'text': div.h4.text,
                    'comments': div.h4.text,
                    'name': name,
                    'url': div.a.get('href'),
                    'embed': embed(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[0]),
                    } for div in video_row][:3]
        return entries


    def save_the_scrapes():

        from_world_star = scrape_and_store_world()
        from_vlad_tv = scrape_and_store_vlad()
        from_pan = panties()
        mergence = from_world_star + from_vlad_tv + from_pan

        random.shuffle(mergence)

        for entry in mergence:
            post = Post()
            post.title = entry['text']
            title = post.title
            if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
                post.title = entry['text']
                post.name = entry['name']
                post.url = entry['url']
                post.body = entry['comments']
                post.image_url = entry['src']
                post.video_path = entry['embed']
                post.status = 'draft'
                post.save()
        return mergence
```

before I added the embed key everything worked fine. If anyone can spot my error please let me know where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please post only the *relevant* code, plus the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is clearly not there, otherwise you would not get a `KeyError`.

You do not set the key in your `scrape_and_store_vlad` method.

```
def scrape_and_store_vlad():
    ...
    entries = [{'href': url_two + div.a.get('href'),
                'src': url_two + div.a.img.get('data-original'),
                'text': div.find('p', 'entry-title').text,
                'comments': make_soup(url_two + div.a.get('href')).replace("\\", ""),
                'name': name,
                'url': url_two + div.a.get('href')
                } for div in titles][:6]
```

Comment: You were right. Sorry been coding long hours and failed to see that